Why do I keep getting an error saying query client isn't set?
I'm trying to use React Query but it's been excruciatingly difficult to setup.  Been stuck on this for like 3hrs already.
I've tried everything under the sun to resolve the Uncaught Error: No QueryClient set, use QueryClientProvider to set one error but to no avail.
If I try to use, for example, useMutation() inside of the <Login/> component, I get the aforementioned error.

I've deleted package-lock.json, node_modules and then ran npm install
Ran npm force cache clear
Tried changing it to older versions in the package,json file

But nothing works.  I keep getting same error.  How's queryClient logging an empty object?  This doesn't make sense at all.  How can I fix this?
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from "@tanstack/react-query";
const queryClient = new QueryClient();

console.log(queryClient); // this logs an empty object

function App() {

    return (
        <>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Route
                    path="/"
                    element={<Login />}
                />
                        <div className="container">
                            <div className="row justify-content-center">
                                <div className="col">
                                    <Routes>
                                        <Route
                                            path="dashboard"
                                            element={<Dashboard />}
                                        />
                                        <Route
                                            path="profile"
                                            element={<Profile />}
                                        />
                                        <Route
                                            path="settings"
                                            element={<Settings />}
                                        />
                                        <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
                                    </Routes>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </>
    );
}

if (document.getElementById("root")) {
    const Index = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));

    Index.render(
        <React.StrictMode>
            <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
                <App />
            </QueryClientProvider>
        </React.StrictMode>
    );
}


This is really strange, let's try some debugging. What's you npm ls @tanstack/react-query? What bundler are you using? What if you log the entire namespace (import * as rq from '@tanstack/react-query' + console.log(rq))?

Is it possible you have two versions of react-query installed? https://github.com/TanStack/query/issues/6432#issuecomment-1826274630

queryClient is a class, so logging the instance will just yield an empty object likely because toString isn't implemented on it. You aren't showing how you are firing the mutation so this question is incomplete and can't be answered.
